# Unable to run Active MQ and Rabbit MQ on the same machine simultaneously

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am trying to run Active MQ and Rabbit MQ on my macbook at the same time, for some project requirement. I didn't change any default configurations, nor did I change any ports. I am able to start (and stop) Active MQ, but when I try to start Rabbit MQ, I get the below error,

```
Starting broker...
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
    init:do_boot/3
    init:start_em/1
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 465
    rabbit:broker_start/1 line 341
    rabbit:start_loaded_apps/2 line 586
    app_utils:manage_applications/6 line 126
    lists:foldl/3 line 1263
    rabbit:'-handle_app_error/1-fun-0-'/3 line 709
throw:{could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,
       {rabbitmq_stomp,
        {{shutdown,
          {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_stomp_listener_sup_:::61613',
           {shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,
             {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613}},
             {shutdown,
              {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
               {listen_error,
                {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613},
                eaddrinuse}}}}}}},
         {rabbit_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
Log file(s) (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,{rabbitmq_stomp,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_stomp_listener_sup_:::61613',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,{ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613}},{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,{listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613},eaddrinuse}}}}}}},{rabbit_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,{rabbitmq_stomp,{{shutdown,{_}},{rabbit_stomp,start,[_]}}}})
```

Now, I do understand that the port 61613 is already in use, and its used by none other than the Active MQ. After digging on the internet, I came to know that I need to change this port on "rabbitmq.config" file. But the problem is, that I was unable to find this file anywhere on my mac.

So, for Plan B, I stopped Active MQ, and was able to start Rabbit MQ successfully. And then, I changed the following ports in /conf/activemq.xml,

```
<transportConnectors>
                <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

for openwire, changed port from 61616 to 61617;
for amqp, changed port from 5672 to 5673;
for stomp, changed port from 61613 to 61615

Now when I try to start Active MQ, I get the following,

```
Rishavs-MacBook-Pro:bin rishavraj$ ./activemq start
INFO: Loading '/Users/rishavraj/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.15.10//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/Users/rishavraj/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.15.10//data/activemq.pid' (pid '42734')
```

But it seems that Active MQ didn't start properly,

```
Rishavs-MacBook-Pro:bin rishavraj$ ./activemq stop
INFO: Loading '/Users/rishavraj/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.15.10//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
ERROR: No or outdated process id in '/Users/rishavraj/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.15.10//data/activemq.pid'

INFO: Removing /Users/rishavraj/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.15.10//data/activemq.pid
```

Please let me know what should I do in order to run them simlutaneously.

Comment: You should be able to locate the files on your mac at these locations https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html

Comment: I checked in `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/` , there were only 2 files, `rabbitmq-env.conf` and `enabled_plugins`, and also, there is no folder named `rabbitmq` inside it, as mentioned in the link you shared for `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE`. I would really appreciate if you kindly help me in resolving the actual location of the config file on my mac. I have been a long time windows user, and just started using mac recently, hence its taking time to getting used to new platform.

Comment: so you need to create the folder and file yourself , since RabbitMQ if it does not fine the config file it falls back on default configuration which is what is happening in your case.

Comment: Please include the information from the ActiveMQ log file referenced after you run `./activemq start`. This should indicate why ActiveMQ didn't start as expected.